# tricky derivative second set of eyes......

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Here is the original function:
[image]

I was wondering if I could get an assist with figuring out the derivative and to see if I was missing any crucial steps in the process.  I have attached an image of the original function but I unfortunately only have written the steps in chicken scratch.  Thank you for your help!

Here are my chicken scratch steps:
[image]

Comment: Your answer $4-1/(2x^\frac32)$ is correct

Comment: The presentation is dreadful. What is the relation of the 2nd line to the first? They aren't equal. The second is not the derivative of the first. A presentation is like a paragraph of written language; it should hold together, not just float away in unconnected bits and pieces. Every equation should be connected to its predecessors, and the connection should be given explicitly. If I saw this on a paper, zero marks.

Comment: It gets worse! Look at that 3rd line! You have used an equals sign --- that means you are asserting the things on either side of it are equal. Are they? Well, are they?? Then, don't write that they are equal, when you know bloody well that they aren't!

Comment: ^Please refrain from adhering to profanity. 
Also, @captain confused, I've updated it.

Comment: One should set up the SPCE: Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to ‘$ = $’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct, and steps are fine as well...

Verification: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+4x+%2B+1%2Fsqrt%28x%29&dataset=

---

Edit:  [image]

Comment: The steps are very far from being fine. They vary from incomprehensible to nonsensical.

Comment: Considering that the OP has clearly mentioned that the steps have been written in chicken scratch, it is fine, for it simply a written translation of the thought process. In case of an exam or such, then only will these steps not suffice/ will be considered incomplete.

Comment: OP wanted to know if he/she was missing any crucial steps in the process. He/she is missing quite a few.

Comment: But where? 4x has been made into 4 in the second step. 3rd and fourth steps are for differentiating the other term...and the fifth step is writing down the final answer. Those seem crucial enough to me...

Comment: OP missed the crucial step of linking the 2nd equation to the 1st, instead of having it just float there; missed the crucial step of making sure the 2nd equation was, in fact, linked to the 1st; missed the crucial step involved in making the third line an equation, instead of the nonsense that it is; missed the crucial step of explaining what on Earth is meant by "simplifying $1/\sqrt x$ into $d/dx$". Mathematiucs isn't just answers; it's communication, and OP fails dismally at that.

Comment: As I said, those are not crucial because the OP explicitly mentioned it was his chicken scratch. For chicken scratch, steps are adequate.

Comment: How would you suggest the proper way is to do it then Gerry?  instead of naysaying, correct me in the error of my ways.... Lots to say but nothing to provide in the form of a true example...

Comment: ^ It's okay man. He just probably wanted to say that your steps are informal and a bit scattered. No need for fights. Also, if you think my answer was good enough for a verification, you can accept it (The tick mark under the upvote/downvote optios)

Comment: I want to see what he has to say though.  No fight picking.  Just for the sake of clarity.  Let the chap come up with his version of proper.

Comment: If the steps are informal and scattered can you or some one else take the time to show me what might be misleading?

Comment: It's pretty clear me :) I don't think they're scattered at all! That's how I would do it on a piece of paper....I mean, you've even put arrow marks to show the process. I find no faults mate. I can still upload a probably 'neater version' (Not to me; maybe to others,- for me your steps are more than enough).

Comment: yeah... if you make a neater one I'll vote yours as correct.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @CaptainConfused Gerry probably was evaluating the answer from an exam point of view (Because you've used an equal-to notation incorrectly in the third line (You mean that the RHS is the derivative)). You explicitly stated that it was chicken scratch, so it's fine for that.

Comment: what would the exam version look like?

Comment: Similar to mine; but you'd also have to mention the rules or concepts used beside the steps in brackets. (Eg: here, the power rule) I'd say your answer is fine if not for formal purposes (Just practice so it's fine), so relax.

Comment: If you want to be certain that I see a comment directed to me, Captain, you have to write @Gerry in it. Otherwise, I don't get notified, and can't know that you are trying to engage with me.

Comment: @GerryMyerson nice.  thanks for the tip.  Appreciate your critique also.  :D